# How to call reduce on an empty Kotlin array?

Tags: reduce, kotlin

Simple reduce on an empty array will throw:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Empty iterable can't be reduced.

The same exception when chaining:

```
val a = intArrayOf()

val b = a.reduce({ memo, next -> memo + next }) // -> throws an exception

val a1 = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)

val b1 = a.filter({ a -> a < 0 }).reduce({ a, b -> a + b }) // -> throws an exception
```

Is it the expected operation of the reduce or is it a bug?

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: FYI: If you are just using `reduce` for summation, then you can use the builtin `.sum()` on lists of numbers and if you are summing stuff that is a bit special, then you can write an extension function to help out as well.

Answer (score 86):

The exception is correct, `reduce` does not work on an empty iterable or array. What you're probably looking for is `fold`, which takes a starting value and an operation which is applied successively for each element of the iterable. `reduce` takes the *first* element as a starting value, so it needs no additional value to be passed as an argument, but requires the collection to be not empty.

Example usage of `fold`:

```
println(intArrayOf().fold(0) { a, b -> a + b })  // prints "0"
```

Comment: Thank you, the fold seems the solution :)
So as I can understand the chained filtering and reducing is risky because the filter can give back an empty list and the reduce will always be called so exception will thrown.

Comment: Why don't you define `reduce` similarly to how it's defined in ECMAScript 6? Let `reduce` take two parameters, the function and an initial value. If no initial value is defined (aka `null`), `reduce` assumes the first value in the array as initial value.

Comment: Did they call it `reduce`?  If so, people looking for `fold` may not realize they need to `reduce` when they want to `fold`.  If they also provide `fold`, then they've created two ways to do the exact same thing.  Either way, that seems like it would create additional barriers for programmers.  I don't think it would be appropriate for the language; however, we can still achieve the same thing by creating our own function if we find we need/want that sort of shorthand.

Answer (score 19):

I just want to add more general approach for situations where it is not possible to use `fold(...)`. Because, in order to use `fold` you need to be able to express some initial value.

```
someIterable
    .filter { TODO("possibly filter-out everything") }
    .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
    ?.reduce { acc, element -> TODO("merge operation") }
    ?: TODO("value or exception for empty")
```

With this approach, in case of an empty collection, `reduce` won't be executed because `takeIf` will convert it to `null`. And at the end we can use elvis operator to express some value (or throw exception) in that case.

Your example:

```
intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    .filter { a -> a < 0 }
    .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
    ?.reduce { a, b -> a + b }
    ?: 0
```

### EDIT:

Since kotlin 1.4, there is stdlib function [`reduceOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce-or-null.html) which is more suitable than `.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }` approach.

Generic case:

```
someIterable
    .filter { TODO("possibly filter-out everything") }
    .reduceOrNull { acc, element -> TODO("merge operation") }
    ?: TODO("value or exception for empty")
```

Used for your problem:

```
intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    .filter { a -> a < 0 }
    .reduceOrNull { a, b -> a + b }
    ?: 0
```

Comment: how to add break point while using reduce.? on string.?

Comment: You can simply break on lambda body and it will break for every reduce substep allowing you to inspect `a` and `b`

Comment: thanks for reply what I did is I used take(numberOfItem) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
public inline fun <S, T : S> List<T>.reduceRightDefault(defaultIfEmpty: S, operation: (T, acc: S) -> S): S {
    return if (isEmpty()) defaultIfEmpty
    else reduceRight(operation)
}
```

usage:

```
val result = listOf<Boolean>().reduceRightDefault(false) { first, second -> first && second}

println("result $result")//result false
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use foldRight:

```
println(listOf("1", "2", "3")
    .filter { "not found" == it }
    .foldRight("") { a, b -> a + b }) // prints: ""

println(listOf("1", "2", "3")
    .filter { "not found" != it }
    .foldRight("") { a, b -> a + b }) // prints: "123"
```

or in your case:

```
val a = intArrayOf()
val b = a.foldRight(0) { memo, next -> memo + next } // b == 0
val a1 = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val b1 = a.filter { a -> a < 0 }.foldRight(0) { a, b -> a + b } // b1 == 0
```